# Google Map API not plotting array of markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need some advice or a telling off because my code is wrong. I'm new to JQuery and google maps api. I have a JSON get to retrieve my data. I have declared an array and stored (hopefully this is the correct way to do this).

update** - Thanks to @geocodezip I have updated my code to allow correct population of array.

When I run my application the map loads fine but no markers. 
I have changed my Google maps initializeMap() to the asynchronous version

```
function initializeMap() {


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(citylat, citylng),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < carparksArray.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(carparksArray[i][1], carparksArray[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(carparksArray[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

    }
```

[My array in console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBFau.png)

I now have an array populated, but still no markers on my map.

This is my whole script. Maybe there are some major flaws.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 



<script type="text/javascript">
    //define variables
    var geocoder;
    var citylat = 0;
    var citylng = 0;
    var carparksArray = [];

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function successFunction(position)
    {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        codeLatLng(lat, lng)
    }

    function errorFunction()
    {
        alert("Geocoder failed");
    }


    function initialize()
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    //get city of current location and runs codeAddress()
    function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        geocoder.geocode({ latLng: latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    var arrAddress = results;
                    console.log(results);
                    $.each(arrAddress, function (i, address_component) {
                        if (address_component.types[0] == "postal_town") {
                            itemPostalTown = address_component.address_components[0].long_name;
                            document.getElementById("town").value = itemPostalTown;
                            codeAddress();



                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    }



    //get latlong of city and runs getCarParks()
    function codeAddress() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById("town").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                citylat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                citylng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                getCarParksLatLng();   

            }

            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    //sets map up
    function initializeMap() {


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(citylat, citylng),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < carparksArray.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(carparksArray[i][1], carparksArray[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(carparksArray[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

    }
    //loads map
    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initializeMap";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    //get carparks names 
    function getCarParksLatLng() {

        var town = document.getElementById("town").value;
        var carparkList = "<p>";

        var uri = "http://localhost/api/carparks?$filter=Town%20eq%20%27" + town + "%27";
        $.getJSON(uri,
             function (data) {
                 carparksArray = [];
                 $('#here_data').empty(); // Clear existing text.
                 // Loop through the list of carparks.
                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                     carparksArray.push([val.Name, val.Latitude, val.Longitude]);

                 });
                 console.log(carparksArray);
             });

        loadScript();
    }
    $(document).ready(initialize)

</script>
```

Comment: Does `getJSON` actually return any data? And when do you call `initializeMap`? If `getJson` hasn't completed when you call `initializeMap`  your array will be empty.

Comment: Use `console.log(carparks);` instead of `alert`. It will tell you more about the tested variable.

Comment: @Turnip my getJSON does work. In the alert it brings in the data. I'll attach an image of the alert. Maybe the array isn't in the correct format.

Comment: @cdm thanks, I'll use this in future. It was the easiest t hing for me to do at the time

Comment: @Turnip hi, I have now attached an image and description of what happens with the data.

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous, you need to use the data (call initializeMap) in the callback function when/where it is available.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `carparks` (in text, not a picture).

Comment: @geocodezip thats for this advice. I have moved the code which initializes the map into the getJSON function. This has fixed my issue and the map is now plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the entries to the `carparkArray` correctly.  Each array element needs to be an array, so the array looks like this:

```
var carparksArray = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  // ...
  ];
```

updated code:

```
var carparks = [];
$.getJSON(uri,
   function (data) {
     $('#here_data').empty(); // Clear existing text.
     // Loop through the list of carparks.
     $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        carparks.push([val.Name, val.Latitude, val.Longitude]);
     });
   });
  loadScript();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8nwu6o8w/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I now have an array in my console.log. Just to get markers on my map now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help on this. Because @geocodezip stated that
$.getJSON is asynchronous I moved my loadscript() function call inside the getJSON function and it now plots the map points.

```
$.getJSON(uri,
             function (data) {
                 carparksArray = [];
                 $('#here_data').empty(); // Clear existing text.
                 // Loop through the list of carparks.
                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                     carparksArray.push([val.Name, val.Latitude, val.Longitude]);

                 });
                 console.log(carparksArray);
                 loadScript();
             });
```